# Add page title to title and chart title to subtitle in Iron python

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I am trying to export a Spotfire page into a PowerPoint presentation. I can export the charts in specific slides successfully but I can't add the page title in the TITLE section and the chart title in the SUBTITLE Section.

I am not sure whether it's possible or not. Can anyone kindly help me?

The current code is not adding anything in the TITLE section at all.

```
from System.IO import *
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from System.Drawing import Bitmap, Graphics, Rectangle, Point
import clr
clr.AddReference("Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint")
import Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint as PowerPoint

powerpoint = PowerPoint.ApplicationClass()
powerpoint.Visible = True
pres=powerpoint.Presentations.Add()
slideCounter = 1

# LOOPING THROUGH ALL THE PAGES
# for page in Document.Pages:
    # Document.ActivePageReference = page

page = Document.Pages[0]
Document.ActivePageReference = page

for visual in Document.ActivePageReference.Visuals:
    print visual.Title

    #export graphic to temp file
    vc = visual.As[VisualContent]()
    bm = Bitmap(2000, 1200)
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    r = Rectangle(Point(0,0), bm.Size)
    vc.Render(g, r)
    file = Path.GetTempFileName()
    bm.Save(file)

    #pp setup
    slide=pres.Slides.Add(slideCounter, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    slideCounter = slideCounter+1
    slide.Shapes.AddPicture((file), False, True, 30, 60, 650, 400)
    title=slide.Shapes.Title
    print(title)
    print(page.Title)
    txt=slide.Shapes.AddTextBox(1,10,500,500,100)
    title.Top=0.1
    obj=slide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
    obj.Font.Size=24
```